# grep regexp [A-Z] returns digits

Tags: grep

I have file `a.txt` with its content as

```
1 (C##2)
2 (C##U)
```

and using `grep` on it

```
cat a.txt | grep '##[A-Z]*'    
1 (C##2)    
2 (C##U)
```

Why did number `1 (C##2)` appear in this grep result? I wanted only second one to
appear. So I have specified `[A-Z]`. Why did it take `..##2` as match?

Answer (score 5):

`[A-Z]*` is *zero* or more occurrences of `[A-Z]`. There are zero occurrences of `[A-Z]` in `##2`, so the line matches. You probably want one or more (`\{1,\}` (or `\+` with GNU `grep` or compatible), or `+` with the `-E` option enabling EREs), or simply `##[A-Z]` as if it matches `##[A-Z]`, it also matches `##[A-Z]+` and vice-versa.

Also note that except in the `C`/`POSIX` locale, what is matched by `[A-Z]` is unspecified and the list of characters (or even possibly collation elements made of several characters) it matches varies with the locale and operating system. On GNU systems, it's generally only characters of the Latin script (including things like `ǅ` or `É`) often only uppercase ones, but sometimes also lowercase ones including the English a-z letters (like in the Thai locale for Thailand on Ubuntu 18.04 at least). You get much more exotic lists in some non-GNU systems like Solaris. To match on ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ only, use `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.

Comment: Thank you. ...grep '#[A-Z]\+' works.
But still amused by "Zero or more matches"... Is it helpful anywhere(any example)? searching for "zero matches" is same as not searching for it at all, isn't it?

Comment: At the start or end of a regex, it isn't that useful, but in between, sure. Say `a[a-zA-Z]*_` .. a string that begins with `a` and has an underscore somewhere in it, but arbitrary alphabets in between.

Comment: @mandrake00 do read Stéphane Chazelas's edit on the answer as well.